# List all Communication site using sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there SharePoint rest api to all retrieve communication site ?
similar to following command

```
Get-PnPTenantSite -WebTemplate SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below endpoint to retrieve all communication sites:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site webtemplate=SITEPAGEPUBLISHING'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the below in Power Automate, and filter seems to have worked for *Publishing* site. You can try replacing filter value with communication site's template id.

```
/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title,WebTemplate&$filter=WebTemplate eq 'CMSPUBLISHING'
```